# Смена раскладки в windows 10

Tags: windows

Как в windows 10 назначить смену раскладки на alt+пробел?

Comment: Попробуйте программным способом:  Auto Hotkey, Key Remapper, Mkey и т.п. Как получится, расскажите.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в настройках.
Пуск -> Параметры -> Время и язык -> Язык -> Настройки для ввода клавиатуры и проверки орфографии -> Дополнительные параметры клавиатуры -> Параметры языковой панели -> Переключение клавиатуры -> Сменить сочетание клавиш

Comment: Там можно сменить только на стандарные: ctrl+shift, alt+shift ...